# Is this question on or off-topic for our site?

Tags: discussion, support, migration, vote-to-close

[This post](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/54714/use-of-asyndeton-in-a-list-preceded-by-a-colon?noredirect=1#comment94511_54714) asks a good question. I am wondering if we should migrate it to EL&U SE though, it seems like too specific of a grammar question for our site. I am asking here on Meta, so as I gradually unlock new privileges I would be able to vote for closure with confidence in my knowledge over grammar questions like [this](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/54714/use-of-asyndeton-in-a-list-preceded-by-a-colon?noredirect=1#comment94511_54714) one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ELU mod writes (on the suitability of the question for ELU):

While discrete questions of grammar are probably more suited to ELU than writers, in this particular case the question would probably end up rejected by being closed.

Using asyndeton [omitting all *and*s in a list] or polysyndeton [putting *and* between all elements in a list] is not really a matter of grammar. It's a stylistic treatment, and both forms have recognised names which your OP knows and uses. It makes no difference how the list is introduced or formatted; a list is a list. Whether it's laid out as in the question, or set out as bullet points, *and* can be included or omitted equally validly.

A question like "Is there a name for omitting all mentions of *and* in a list?" or "What do we call it when children breathlessly add *and* between everything when listing their day's activities?" would certainly be on-topic and answerable on ELU.

A question which is really "Does this use or omission of *and* suit my writing style?" would be off-topic on ELU and closed as opinion-based.

I'll leave Writers mods to comment about this site, its handling of topicality and migration mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @AndrewLeach for the ELU perspective.

I agree that the question is probably more stylistic than it is grammar so I think we'll leave it where it is. I've added the 'style' tag to the question.

Comment: By the same token, though, would that not leave it far too opinion-based, even for us?

Comment: @WeckarE. possibly..I think it may lack enough context to give a definitive answer but I'll leave that one to the community to decide for now.